# Subtract rows by time and ID

Tags: r, list, plyr

I have a dataset like this:

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(
Year = rep(2000, times=16),
Month = rep(1:2, each=8),
group = rep(c("ABC","ABc","Abc","AbC","aBC","aBc","abc", "abC"),times=2),
A_gr = rep(c("A","A","A","A","a","a","a","a"), times=2),
V = rnorm(16)
)
```

Where A, B and C can have either the form of a capital or a small letter.
For each point in time (month + year) and group combination I now want to subtract the V-value of the capital letter version from the small letter version. So aBC-ABC, aBc-ABc etc.

With only 2 group letters I managed to do that with order, list and by but I cannot make that work here. I also experimented with plyr but did not succeed neither. Any ideas?

Further I wonder if it is possible to subtract the sum of all four capital letter versions from the sum of the small letter versions in one step, so (aBC+aBc+abc+abC)-(ABC+ABc+Abc+AbC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create another grouping variable ('gr') by changing the first character in 'group' to upper case using `sub`, then use that in the `by` along with 'Month' and 'Year', get the difference between 'V' that corresponds to "A" and "a" in 'A_gr', and assign the 'gr' to NULL (if needed).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(group = paste(group[2L],group[1L], 
        sep="-"),Diffs=V[A_gr=="A"]- V[A_gr=="a"]), 
       by =  .(gr=sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", group, perl=TRUE), Month, Year)][, gr:= NULL][]
#   Month Year   group      Diffs
#1:     1 2000 aBC-ABC -0.2757990
#2:     1 2000 aBc-ABc -0.5740468
#3:     1 2000 abc-Abc -0.1632544
#4:     1 2000 abC-AbC -0.2354917
#5:     2 2000 aBC-ABC -1.3884391
#6:     2 2000 aBc-ABc -1.2439231
#7:     2 2000 abc-Abc  0.3603894
#8:     2 2000 abC-AbC  0.6664342
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table` to convert from 'long' from 'wide' format after creating another variable ('gr') by extracting the `substring` in 'group'.  We take the difference between the "V_A" and "V_a" columns from the `dcast` output.

```
setDT(df)[, gr:= substring(group, 2)]
dcast(df, Year+Month+gr~A_gr, value.var=c("V", "group"))[, 
  .(group = paste(group_A, group_a, sep="-"), Diffs = V_A- V_a), .(Year, Month)]
#   Year Month   group      Diffs
#1: 2000     1 ABC-aBC -0.2757990
#2: 2000     1 ABc-aBc -0.5740468
#3: 2000     1 AbC-abC -0.2354917
#4: 2000     1 Abc-abc -0.1632544
#5: 2000     2 ABC-aBC -1.3884391
#6: 2000     2 ABc-aBc -1.2439231
#7: 2000     2 AbC-abC  0.6664342
#8: 2000     2 Abc-abc  0.3603894
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Just to understand more of the dynamics of the code: What does the "\\U\\1" and perl-arguments stand for in solution 1 and what does the 2 stand for in the substring command in solution 2?

Comment: @faremi The `\\U\\1` stands for converting the captured group to upper case.  `\\1` is the backreference for the captured group (`(.)`), it matches the first character and convert to upper case.  In the `substring`, we use the `start` position as 2.  So all characters from 2 to end of the string gets extracted.

Comment: That makes sense! Learned something new. :)
Is there a smarter solution to do what I describe in my follow up question above than to apply your algorithm four times?

Comment: @faremi I didn't check your update earlier.  It seems like you want to use the `setDT(df)[,sum(V[A_gr=="a"])- sum(V[A_gr=="A"]) , .(Year, Month)]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way of transforming your data by removing the `a` or `A` information from the group column since it is also provided by `A_gr` and then use `tidyr` package to transform the data from `long` to `wide` format which makes it much easier to calculate the difference.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(group = gsub("[A|a]", "", group)) %>% 
       spread(A_gr, V) %>% mutate(diffV = A - a) %>% 
       select(Year, Month, group, diffV)

  Year Month group    diffV
1 2000     1    bc -0.16325
2 2000     1    bC -0.23549
3 2000     1    Bc -0.57405
4 2000     1    BC -0.27580
5 2000     2    bc  0.36039
6 2000     2    bC  0.66643
7 2000     2    Bc -1.24392
8 2000     2    BC -1.38844
```

Comment: Thanks for this smart solution! Does this also solve my edited follow up question?